# merging cells in ssrs 2014

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2014

I am using ssrs in visual Studio 2013

[image]

In my report each reference has 1 or more visits. Each record has the same data for each reference except for the date. I have managed to hide the data if the previous record is the same as per the pic about. I was wondering if I can merge the date field so that all the date only display in the first cell and this making the report look neater

thanks

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you want the report to look like but the basic principle is to group by everything that can repeat in order or significance. So your grouping might be Area/Customer/Premises/Reference and your details would be date plus whatever else you need.

Comment: Thanks Alan, I have added an extra Pic. I know its been a bit pedantic but I wondered if it is possible where all the dates are in one row. Is the only way to do it is to add a sub report?

Comment: OK, So basically everthing within the reference is identical except a list of dates, is that correct?

Comment: yes That is correct

Comment: Unless I'm missing something... Just create a table, add your date field to the details group (details has no grouping set). Then add a parent group, grouped by reference. Right click the reference cell and do "insert column/inside group/right" for each column you need (name, address etc) and that should be it. You'll still get dates on separate rows but it should look OK, If this is not what you expect then draw a mock up of what you expected output looks like and I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one trick to go about that.

Add a variable in the custom code to toggle returning the value. Use this along with two custom code functions bound to the text of your column and column header to produce the desired result.

NOTE : This code is off the top of my head and will doubtfully compile.

```
Public Shared Dim DoPrint As Boolean = false

Public Procedure GetDateValue(dateValue As String) As String
Begin
  Dim Result As String=""
  If(DoPrint) Then
     Result=dateValue
     DoPrint=false
  Else 
     Result=""
  End If
  Return Result
End Procedure

Public Procedure AllowPrintAndReturn(returnValue As String) As String
Begin
  DoPrint = true
  Return returnValue     
End Procedure
```

---

```
<ColumnHeader> =Code!AllowPrintAndReturn(Fields!DateHeader.Value)
<DateField>    =Code!GetDateValue(Fields!DateField.Value)
```